# How to replace part of string with a character

Tags: python

I'm trying to creating a code that prints till 'n' and replaces the rest of the characters with "*".
This is my code so far"

```
def replace(s,n):
    return s.replace(s[n:], "*")
```

However it outputs

```
    replace("hello", 2)
   'he*'
```

it should be 'he***'

Comment: Did you try counting how many characters it would replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should multiply `"*"` by the number of characters you want to replace. In addition, you should add `(len(s)-n)*"*"` after `s[n:]` instead of replacing (as the same set of characters may appear in several places in the string). You may do that as follows:

```
def replace(s,n):
    return s[:n]+(len(s)-n)*"*"
replace('hello', 2)
```

This prints `'he***'`

Answer (score 1):

There are two fundamental issues. First, `s.replace` will replace the entire first argument with the second. And perhaps even more important, *it replaces it anywhere it finds it on the string*. So, consider the following example:

```
>>> def replace(s,n):
...     return s.replace(s[n:], "*")
...
>>> replace('lalahahalala', 8)
'*haha*'
>>>
```

Instead, you should take a different approach, iterate the string, returning the character in that string if the index is `< n`, else, return `'*'`:

```
>>> def replace(s, n):
...     return ''.join(c if i < n else '*' for i,c in enumerate(s))
...
>>> replace("hello", 2)
'he***'
>>> replace('lalahahalala', 8)
'lalahaha****'
```

Here is a version of the above using a for-loop instead of a generator expression:

```
>>> def replace(s, n):
...     char_list = []
...     for i, c in enumerate(s):
...         if i < n:
...             char_list.append(c)
...         else:
...             char_list.append('*')
...     return ''.join(char_list)
...
>>> replace('hello', 2)
'he***'
>>> replace('lalahahalala', 8)
'lalahaha****'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` approach is fundamentally flawed, because `replace` looks for a substring to replace anywhere in the source string, it's not for replacing characters at some position. Even with the "fixed" version by @MiriamFarber (now he edited it, look at the revision history) you'd get erroneous output like

```
replace("chachacha", 6) # returns *********
```

What you want is to truncate the string at the requested position, and append to it a string of as many asterisks as the characters you removed.

```
def replace(s, n):
    return s[:n] + '*'*(len(s)-n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice `s` until `n` position and then concatenate the rest of the string using `*` operator. You don't need to use `replace` method:

```
def replace(s,n):
    return s[:n] + (len(s)-n)*'*'
```

The output is:

```
replace('hello', 2)
'he***'
```